# Wordpress - Pagination is not working?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

the following is the code in my home.php, it works but not the pagination, what am i doing wrong, or is there a better way to write the code to make it work? please help.

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

echo "<div id=\"featured_post\">";
    query_posts( array ('post_type'=>'post', 'paged' => $paged, 'category_name' => $featured_cat_name, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1 ) );
    $fcount = 1;
    if (!$paged):
        while ( have_posts() && $fcount < 5 ) : the_post();?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="view"><?php
                $format = get_post_format();
                if ( false == $format ):
                featured_posts_first();
                else :
                featured_posts_test();
                endif;                      
          echo "</div>";
        $fcount++;
        endwhile;
    else :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php if (get_post_format() == audio): echo 'audio-isa view'; else : echo 'view'; endif; ?>"><?php

                featured_posts_test();

            echo "</div>";
        endwhile;
    endif;
echo "</div>";
    //get posts navigation
    global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
    thematic_navigation_below();
    }
    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you use a pagination plug-in such as [simple pagination](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-pagination/) - very easy to use.

alternatively use [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/)